# Change Django modelForm Foreign Key field to Text Field

Tags: django, django-models

I have to generate a form for adding member to model which is Foreign Key to User model. It gives me dropdown field, how can i make it a charfield.

models.py:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    """Stores pairs of Group and User whenever a User is added"""
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = False)
    group_name = models.ForeignKey(TaskGroupList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('member', 'group_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.member) + " in " + str(self.group_name)
```

forms.py:

```
class MemberAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = ['member']
```

This form gives me a dropdown field for "member" as it is a Foreign Key. So how can i make it normal Text Field.

Comment: please edit your question  with your codes

Comment: You can make use of a package like [**`django-autocomplete-light`**](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: I have added the code.